# How to return zero in a group by clause when no records exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

We record the volume of sales on an hourly basis for every product we sell.  When there are no sales for a product during an hour, there is no record.  We are trying to create a query that will tell us the minimum number of items sold, per product, per day.  We have that working correctly but we don't know how to handle the case where there is no record in one or more hours thus making the correct result zero.  Essentially, our query will never return zero because it picks the minimum number in the records where there was at least one sale.

Note that all of the time stamps are at the start of every hour; minutes and seconds are always 0.

Our query so far looks like this:

```
SELECT activity_time
      ,min(hourly_quantity) AS daily_min_quantity
      ,product_name 
FROM (select cast(quantity_time AS date) AS quantity_time
            ,sum(hourly_quantity) AS hourly_quantity
            ,product_name 
      FROM Hourly_Sales 
      GROUP BY activity_time,product_name ) x 
group by activity_time,product_name
```

I'm thinking we need to do either a count of the hours in the subquery to make sure there are 24 and if not, return zero but I'm not sure quite how to do that.

Comment: That is not even a valid query

Answer (score 1):

You need an outer most select returning a distinct list of your products and a `LEFT JOIN` to your sales data. Every product with `NULL` as sales data is a product with not existent sales. Use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to deal with this.

If you provide some more details on your (missing) tables (especially the product, I could help you further...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach the creation of a 'results per period' style report is to use a date & time table (or CTE) to create a set of datetimes, then `LEFT JOIN` these to your query and `ISNULL` to apply defaults.

Date & Time tables make this kind of thing easy and fast, but here's a pseudo-TSQL version using a CTE and 15 min reporting periods:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2 = '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME2 = '2016-01-31 23:45:00';
DECLARE @Period INT = 15; 

WITH Dates AS
(
  SELECT @StartDate DatePeriod
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @Period, D.DatePeriod) Date FROM Dates D
  WHERE D.DatePeriod < @EndDate
)
SELECT D.DatePeriod
    ,ISNULL(MyColumn1, 0) MyColumn1
    --etc 
 FROM Dates D
    LEFT JOIN (
      --SELECT GOES HERE
    ) MyData ON MyData.SomeDateTime = D.DatePeriod
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're grouping by "activity_time,product_name" in your subquery, and then again in your query by "activity_time, product_name" (I'm guessing you forgot to put activity_time in SELECT part of subquery) aren't you getting same results from your SUM and MIN aggregates?